# Select element corresponding to maximum/minimum value in different column

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find the value corresponding to maximum value in another column in my array, but get an error with the present code saying Unable to cast object of type `WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[Main.AllClasses.MaxMin,System.Int32] to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

I am assigning a list of type `MaxMin` to an array and then trying to calculate the `maxima` and its corresponding element in the second column.
Here's the code:

```
MaxMin finalMax = new MaxMin();
if (maxima.Count != 0)
{
      MaxMin[] maxArray = maxima.ToArray();
      finalMax.val = maxArray.Select(x => x.val).Max();
      finalMax.cnt = Convert.ToInt32(maxArray.Where(x => x.val.Equals(finalMax.val)).Select(x => x.cnt));
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
public MaxMin Maxima(float[] values, MaxMin drop)
    {
        float[] T = new float[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        float[] dT = new float[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int count = 0;
        List<MaxMin> maxima = new List<MaxMin>();


        count = values.Length;


        try
        {
            for (int i = 99; i < count - 100; i++)
            {
                MaxMin max = new MaxMin();

                T[0] = values[i - 1];
                T[1] = values[i];
                T[2] = values[i + 1];
                T[3] = values[i + 2];
                T[4] = values[i + 3];

                dT[0] = T[1] - T[0];
                dT[1] = T[2] - T[1];
                dT[2] = T[3] - T[2];
                dT[3] = T[4] - T[3];


                if (i > drop.cnt)     //cutoff time above which calculation of minima will be initiated
                {
                    if (dT[1] > 0 && dT[3] < 0)
                    {
                        float[] diff = new float[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                        diff[0] = (values[i + 1] - values[i - 19]);
                        diff[1] = (values[i + 1] - values[i + 19]);
                        diff[2] = (values[i + 1] - values[i - 49]);
                        diff[3] = (values[i + 1] - values[i + 49]);
                        diff[4] = (values[i + 1] - values[i - 69]);
                        diff[5] = (values[i + 1] - values[i + 69]);
                        diff[6] = (values[i + 1] - values[i - 99]);
                        diff[7] = (values[i + 1] - values[i + 99]);

                        if (diff[0] < 20 && diff[1] < 20 && diff[2] < 20 && diff[3] < 20 && diff[2] > 0 && diff[3] > 0 && diff[4] > 0.5 && diff[5] > 0.5 && diff[6] > 2 && diff[7] > 2)
                        {
                            max.cnt = i + 1;
                            max.val = values[i + 1];
                            maxima.Add(max);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            MaxMin finalMax = new MaxMin();

            if (maxima.Count != 0)
            {
                MaxMin[] maxArray = maxima.ToArray();
                finalMax.val = maxArray.Select(x => x.val).Max();
                finalMax.cnt = Convert.ToInt32(maxArray.Where(x => x.val.Equals(finalMax.val)).Select(x => x.cnt));
            }

            else
            {
                finalMax.val = values.Max();
                finalMax.cnt = Array.IndexOf(values, values.Max());
            }


            return finalMax;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
  }
```

Comment: You may need to do something like finalMax.val = maxArray.Select(x => x.val).Max().<some field>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert results of `Select` method call, which returns `IEnumerable<T>`, to `int`. That's not gonna work.

Use `First` instead of `Where`/`Select`:

```
finalMax.cnt = maxArray.First(x => x.val.Equals(finalMax.val)).cnt;
```